# Pexpect - silence ssh connection output

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I'm using a simple pexpect script to ssh to a remote machine and grab a value returned by a command.
Is there any way, pexpect or sshwise I can use to ignore the unix greeting?
That is, from

```
    child = pexpect.spawn('/usr/bin/ssh %s@%s' % (rem_user, host))
    child.expect('[pP]assword: ', timeout=5)
    child.sendline(spass)
    child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, prompt])
    child.before = '0'
    child.sendline ('%s' % cmd2exec)
    child.expect([pexpect.EOF, prompt])

    # Collected data processing
    result = child.before
    # logon to the machine returns a lot of garbage, the returned executed command is at the 57th position
    print result.split('\r\n') [57]
    result = result.split('\r\n') [57]
```

How can I simply get the returned value, ignoring,
the "Last   successful login" and "(c)Copyright" stuff 
and without having to concern with the value correct position?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to the server to which you are logging in, you can try creating a file named `.hushlogin` in the home directory. The presence of this file silences the standard MOTD greeting and similar stuff.

Alternatively, try `ssh -T`, which will disable terminal allocation entirely; you won't get a shell prompt, but you may still issue commands and read the response.

There is also a similar thread on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/36421/stop-ssh-login-from-printing-motd-from-the-client) which may be of some use to you.

Comment: Thanks. I've access to the host but don't have permission to edit nothing there. ssh -t works beautifully.

Answer (score 4):

If the command isn't interactive, you can just run `ssh HOST COMMAND` to run the command without all the login excitement happening at all.  If the command *is* interactive, you can frequently use the ssh `-t` option (`ssh -t HOST COMMAND`) to force pseudo-tty allocation and trick the remote process to think that it's running attached to a TTY.

Answer (score 0):

I have used paramiko to automate ssh connection and I have found it useful. It can deal with greetings and silent execution.

- http://www.lag.net/paramiko/

Comment: Thanks. 
Already bumped into it when I've discovered pexpect but didn't give it a try. Will do this time.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there you kann kill all that noise by using the sys module and a small class:

```
class StreamToLogger(object):
   """
   Fake file-like stream object that redirects writes to a logger instance.
   """
   def __init__(self, logger, log_level=logging.INFO):
      self.logger = logger
      self.log_level = log_level
      self.linebuf = ''

   def write(self, buf):
       for line in buf.rstrip().splitlines():
           self.logger.log(self.log_level, line.rstrip())


#Mak
stdout_logger = logging.getLogger('STDOUT')
sl = StreamToLogger(stdout_logger, logging.INFO)
sys.stdout = sl



stderr_logger = logging.getLogger('STDERR')
sl = StreamToLogger(stderr_logger, logging.ERROR)
sys.stderr = sl
```

Can't remember where i found that snippet but it works for me :)